# How do I get test data running functions locally?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have the following:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send(request.body);
});
```

I ran it locally and ran `helloWorld("Hey")`, and this was the output:

```
firebase > helloWorld('HEY')
Sent request to function.
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Execution took 1 ms, user function completed successfully

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, "{}"
```

Why does it only output `{}` when I clearly sent it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you invoke HTTP type functions locally.  You should review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_https_functions) and use the patterns established there.  You invoke the method as if you were using the node request module:

> For invoking HTTPS functions in the shell, usage is the same as the
>   request NPM module, but replace request with the name of the function
>   you want to emulate. For example:
>
> ```
> # invoke
> myHttpsFunction()
> myHttpsFunction.get()
> myHttpsFunction.post()
>
> # invoke at sub-path
> myHttpsFunction('/path')
> myHttpsFunction.get('/path')
> myHttpsFunction.post('/path')
>
> # send POST request with form data
> myHttpsFunction.post('/path').form( {foo: 'bar' })
> ```

I'm not sure you're able to specify the entire content body.  That seems like an uncommon case, since you usually pass parameters to an HTTP function via its query string, or a form encoded body.

Comment: Thanks Doug. But the documentation gave examples like that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#serve_functions_using_a_cloud_functions_shell). They do it like the way I did: `myFunctionName(data, options)`. I actually got it from the documentation. I'm confused.

Comment: Which example?  Is it specifically for HTTP functions, which I linked you directly to?

Comment: It's above the section you linked in your documentation. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/SVMJPPb.png)'s a screenshot.

Comment: That's just showing you how you can load your test data without having to type it in.  You really should read my answer again.  Your function should be expecting to receive input via form or query string, and your local invocation should be specifying what that parameterized data is.  You can't just pass in the entire content body as you are now.